# What are the best practices for a lot of strings and other contents organized? [Android]

Tags: android

I want to make an android app which will contain a lot of chapters (around 100) and each chapters will have specific pictures, audio and descriptions. Later I want to add translations too. I'm a beginner and have no academic background till now. Can you please tell me how should I design the app? I'm thinking of implementing list view for the chapters list. Fragments to display information. What are the best practices if I want to keep the chapters with vast number of strings and other contents organized and display flawlessly?

Comment: Welcome to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com). Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Please read **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

Comment: Okay, Thank you for explaining. I'll come up with a more specific questions next time.

Comment: *how should I design the app?* There are many websites available in google so find there. if you have any programmatic issue then please paste your answer hear

Comment: This is very broad and opinion based. You should go through some tutorials, build some apps for practice. That will give you a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @SanSolo. Of course I should gain some experiences too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all your strings to `your_language.xml`, and then you can create other xml files  (`french.xml, english.xml...`) with translations, where you store strings with same names, but translated text, and depending on choosen language, they're going to be replaced. Keep `strings.xml` to store strings just for app, like version, author name, or other stuff which you don't need to translate.

Comment: This is precisely what I needed to know! Thanks a lot.